# Different User Points for different nodes

Tags: 7, rules, users, userpoints

I am using the [User Points](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints) module to assign points to users if they post some content and so on. Works great. Now the admin can set some tasks to the users in the form of nodes. To be clear, a node would describe to perform some tasks and then upload a blog about it. IN that node the admin would assign a field CREDITS which tells how many points a user would get for creating a content related to this node. To relate the nodes i am using References module which works fine. So my question is is there any way to do this, i.e, when admin uploads a new node he can provide the user points in a field which would be the user point assigned to the users when they post a content about this node. I hope i am clear. If any doubt please ask i would only be happy to clarify my doubt.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

User points can be assigned based on default points or their particular points defined in content type form page.

If you want to override that points use [hook_userpoints](http://drupal.org/node/206558) function. In that function points before case will execute before user points is assigned to users.

second parameter in hook_userpoints, you will get points and entity_id using that you can change points based on your condition.

Comment: so i will have to custom code it ?

Comment: yes, you need custom module for that to user hook_userpoints